# How can i transfer all installed plugins to another jenkins?

Tags: jenkins

I want to install same plugins in to my local Jenkins which are already installed in other Jenkins.

Want to avoid installing all the 50-60 odds plugin manually

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The official [Jenkins documentation](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/managing/plugins/) on installing plugins gives two ways of installing plugins:

1. Via the web interface
2. Save the downloaded `*.hpi`/`*.jpi` file into the `$JENKINS_HOME/plugins` directory.

So my answer to your question would be: copy the `$JENKINS_HOME/plugins` directory from server A to server B.

Don't forget to restart Jenkins afterwards!

Comment: Feel free to accept my answer if it answered your question. :)

Comment: @sandejai : http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow

Comment: Thanks Jayan, because Sandejai didn't actually accept, they just upvoted.

Comment: "Don't forget to restart Jenkins afterwards!"

Comment: The link URL is broken now.

Comment: @cowlinator I updated the URL. Thank you for reporting. However, you do not need the URL, because I have included the full answer inline.

Answer (score 2):

There's another way, that's ideal if you're using Jenkins inside a docker container, first you need to extract a list of installed plugins by running curl against your jenkins domain in terminal:

```
export JENKINS_URL=http://<jenkins_domain>
curl -sSL "$JENKINS_URL/pluginManager/api/xml?depth=1&xpath=/*/*/shortName|/*/*/version&wrapper=plugins" | perl -pe 's/.*?<shortName>([\w-]+).*?<version>([^<]+)()(<\/\w+>)+/\1 \2\n/g'|sed 's/ /:/'
```

this you return you a list of installed plugins formatted like this:

```
aws-credentials:1.15
aws-beanstalk-publisher-plugin:1.6.0
aws-java-sdk:1.10.45.2
```

Then you can run [this script](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jenkinsci/docker/master/plugins.sh) against the list saved in a txt file to install all the exported plugins or add it to the end of your Dockerfile like this:

```
# copy script to container's bin
ADD ./plugin.sh /usr/local/bin/plugins.sh
# copy plugins list to inside the container
COPY plugins.txt /plugins.txt

# runs it
RUN /usr/local/bin/plugins.sh /plugins.txt
```

Just remember export your JENKINS_HOME variable before doing this.

Comment: That's interesting, but the OP didn't say that Jenkins is running inside a Docker container. As a personal opinion, I think running Jenkins inside Docker is adding unneeded configuration overhead, _but that may depend on the specific situation_. *However*, and I cannot stress this enough, running Jenkins _JOBS_ inside Docker is an *excellent* idea which I would really recommend. Just my 2 cents.

Comment: The URL is currently broken.